# Prove that a solution to differential equation $x'=f(x)$ is bounded with $\left| f(x)-\cos(x)\right|\leq1$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a solution to a Cauchy problem
$$x'=f(x),\quad x(0)=x_0,$$
where $x_0\in\mathbb{R},f\in\mathcal{C}^1\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ and $f$ is such that
$$\forall_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \left|f\left(x\right)-\cos x\right|\leq 1.$$
Prove that for any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ function $x$ is bounded. 
Edit: My partial solution had an error in it and it didn't work. What I've tried was to bound $\int\frac{dx}{f(x)}$ but the $f(x)$ isn't always positive nor negative so it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know about Picard iteration/the Picard-Lindelöf theorem?

It tells you that a solution $\lambda$ of $x' = f(x)$ satisfies $\lambda(t) = x_0 + \displaystyle\int_{0}^t f(\lambda(s)) \mathrm{d}s$ (where $f$ is locally Lipschitzean, so it's true when $f \in \mathcal{C}^1$).

Then, you have $|f(x) - \cos x| \leq 1 \implies |f(x)| \leq 1 + |\cos x| \leq 2$. So in particular:

$|\lambda(t)| \leq x_0 + \displaystyle \int_{0}^t  2 \mathrm{d}s = x_0 + 2t$. This doesn't ensure boundedness of $\lambda$ yet, but it makes sure that it is defined globally. Indeed, the only way for a solution to a Cauchy problem to not be defined globally, is if the solution **blows up in finite time** (*ie,* it goes to infinity at some finite value, which explains why you can't extend it any more).

You can skip this step if you're not interested in the domain of your solution, and all you want to show is that it's bounded (whatever the domain).

---

Now that you know $\lambda$ is defined globally, all you need to do is check that it stays bounded.

A very useful fact, when $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ is that **solutions cannot cross**.

Now, the condition $|f(x) - \cos x| \leq 1$ tells you that $f$ is always within a distance $1$ of $\cos$. This, in particular, tells you that $f$ will have to be $0$ infinitely many times, and you can find zeros as big as you want! (Look at it graphically if you can't see why, it has to do with the fact cosine will oscillate infinitely many times between $1$ and $-1$.)

But if $x^*$ is a zero of $f$, then $x \mapsto x^*$ is a constant solution of your differential equation. So you can find two zeros of $f$, $x_1^*$ and $x_2^*$, such that $x_1^* \leq x_0 \leq x_2^*$.
In particular, since $\lambda$ cannot cross other solutions, it will never be able to leave that box:

[image]

So $\lambda$ is bounded.